# High traffic connection between Php and Redis

Tags: php, sockets, redis, high-traffic

I have backend on php, that works with Redis.

But when requests increased and they more than 2000 request per sec I receive an error:

```
99 - Cannot assign requested address
```

All sockets in TIME_WAIT.

---

Connecting example:

```
$this->_socket = @stream_socket_client(
    'tcp://' . $this->hostname . ':' . $this->port,
    $errorNumber,
    $errorDescription,
    ini_get('default_socket_timeout'),
    STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT
);
```

---

I find solution: http://redis4you.com/articles.php?id=012&name=redis

But /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_recycle I can't set in 1.
Don't want to loss packets on the network between application and redis.

Php on new request from API create a new socket.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you send multiple request using the same socket ?

Comment: How can I send multiple request using the same socket?

Comment: http://redis.io/topics/pipelining

Comment: Is this PHP page called by different clients ?

Comment: Yes and no. It can calling different clients.

Comment: Do you have APC installed on the server ?

Comment: What's the output of `ulimit -a` on your server? I assume you're on some sort of Linux / Unix, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed problem.**
Use tcp reuce and time waite for socket sets in 10 seconds. Php work with socket in persistent mode

```
STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT
```

So even in 2 000 request per second it use not more then 61 sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your whole design, but here something you could do :

- Create a PHP page that always run (with a while(true) loop)
- This page would wait for content from your initial page (where the socket code was before)
- Using the pipelining technique, you would send all requests using the same socket.
- Only thing missing is how to pass data from the initial page to this new page.

For that last part I see multiple solutions (not sure if they all work though) :

- Using APC to store data from initial page and still use it to get it from the new one.
- Create a SESSION in the new page which would than have two modes : Processing, Submitting. You should then call this page using your local server inside the initial page.

In both solutions, one instance of this new page shall be executed locally so the 'Processing/Waiting' is activated.